# Multiple undeclared pods are installed alongside Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I am trying to connect my iOS project to Googles Firestore database. I have added the following pods as I believe these are required when using Analytics and also Firestore.

When running `pod install` after including these pods, I get a lot more pods automatically installed without me explicitly putting them in my podfile.

`pod 'Firebase/Analytics'`
`pod 'FirebaseFirestore'`

My build steps has now gone from about 100 to roughly 3000 and my project takes an age to build. Are these auto installed dependencies required to run the Firestore library or associated functions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highlighted Pods are all required Firebase dependencies.

You can see details about all the Pods and their dependencies in the generated Podfile.lock file.

Firestore, and its dependencies, in particular can take a long time to build. A workaround is to use [this binary distribution](https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks).